# turn c# code into mysql function

Tags: mysql

I have the following code in C# that I would like to turn into a MySQL snippet instead?

```
  foreach (DataRow row in dtBills.Rows)
            {
                classes.UtilityBill ub = new classes.UtilityBill(row);

                if (ub.ApprovedBy > 0)
                {
                    if (ub.RemainingBalance() > 0) { totalOutstanding += ub.RemainingBalance(); numberOfUnpaidBills++; }
                    if (ub.RemainingBalance() > 0 && ub.IsOverDue()) { numberOfOverdueBills++; }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ub.ApprovedBy == 0)
                    {
                        awaitingApproval++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rejectedBills++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

ub.RemainingBlaance() basically checks two fields in the table and subtracts, amount_due - amount_paid

What I'm looking to have returned is a single row that looks something like:

```
totalOutstanding, numberOfUnpaidBills, numberOfOverdueBills, awaitingApproval, rejectedBills
```

Original table:

[image]
I know that this might come across like a lazy question, but I have never dealt with coding in mysql, just simple queries, and I have no idea on how to start. A push in the right direction would suffice, not a complete solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't appear to have any database connection in the above code... What does your table look like? What are your column names?

Comment: My bad, added an image of the table :)

Comment: have you looked into entity relation? that is meant for such things

Comment: Doesnt that rely on using the Entiry Framework?

Comment: yep. I meant to say entity framework. based on the version of .net you are using, it may however not allow you to get from mysql to c#, only the other way. You can also look into linq to sql. However I am providing a code snippet for simplified library got

Comment: Im not using EF.

Comment: `totalOutstanding, numberOfUnpaidBills, numberOfOverdueBills` etc are your db column names right?

Comment: Nope, those are the C# variables that im incrementing based on the row values..

Comment: i posted a sample code in my library. Let me know if you need more specific examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query mysql you can use the `mysql.data` nuget package. You can look up their documentation. I created a nuget to simplify code from any c# framework to mysql as well. If you don't mind third party nugets, you can try it out. It is called `mysql.simple`. From what I understand from what the code is trying to do, here is a small code for pulling data:

```
using (Database db = ConnectionString)  // initializes connection
{
    // you can omit the below select function if you would like to select all
    using (var Row = db.Select("unit_cost, start_reading")
                       From("tblName").Query()
    while(Row.Read()){  // gets each row
        ub.unit_cost = Row["unit_cost"];
        ub.start_reading= Row["start_reading"];
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

The `db` object above has select, update and insert functions with all variations including insert statements with selects. However if you would like to use raw sql queries, you can directly use db.Query("sql query here"). You can see more documentations here http://mysqlsimple.azurewebsites.net/docs

Here is a sample mySql stored procedure I had with me:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_IF;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_IF (IN param1 INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE variable1 INT;
  SET variable1 = param1 + 1;

  IF variable1 = 0 THEN 
    SELECT variable1;
  END IF;

  IF param1 = 0 THEN
    SELECT 'Parameter value = 0' ;
  ELSE
    SELECT 'Parameter value <> 0' ;
  END IF;

END //
```

This example contains parameters, variables and if statement examples.

You can call this in c# something like this:

```
db.QueryValue("CALL proc_IF (@0)", myVal);
```

Comment: Pretty cool nuget! I''l have a look at that. However, it is not really what Im looking for.  What I want, is to have the computations done on the database and then returned as a result, instead of me first querying the database for the rows, and then looping though them and calculating on the server side.

Comment: in this case you can try creating stored procedures in mysql and using them in c#. this also helps you prevent sql injections. however stored procedures in mysql are tricky, at least compared to sql server. If the computations is simple you can use a single sql to generate the code. For instance `SELECT mount_due - amount_paid`

Comment: This is kinda what I’m looking for. I’m used to creating SPs but not usIng IF, Case and variables in them. Was hoping for an example like that.